# Redirect along with the string

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect if the url has the word 'forum' ALONG with the final part after the `?` to be as `?no=get-final-part` using htaccess?

Example:

```
http://www.exsample.com/forum/contactus.html?ypin9001234
```

should be redirected to

```
http://www.exsample.com/homepage.html?no=ypin9001234
```

This is what I did so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exsample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} forum
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exsample.com/no=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ /homepage.html?no=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. +10 May I know where does `?no=` come in your answer? As you can see in my question, the original url is `contactus.html?ypin9001234` and I want it to be as `homepage.html?no=ypin9001234`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I thought `no=` is also there in `forum` URL. Try my updated rule now.

Comment: Thanks. Will the htaccess pick `ypin9001234` as the query string because it is as `?ypin9001234` (not something like `?something=ypin9001234`) ?

Comment: Yes value of `%{QUERY_STRING}` will be `ypin9001234` without `?`

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try now.

Comment: I tried your solution but it dosen't seem to redirect if the word `forum` in somewhere in the URL?

Comment: What is the full URL you are using for testing?

Comment: It goes like `http://www.exsample.com/forum/contactus.html?ypin9001234`

Comment: Also in the same htaccess I have another redirect set for the `www` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exsample.com$ [NC]` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exsample.com/$1 [R=301,L]` Is there a conflict between them in the same htaccess file? Does it need to be combined?

Comment: No. the htaccess is in the root only.

Comment: ok try keep my modified rule as your very first rule and retest. It worked in my testing.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I'll let you know the test results.